# What name for bowdlerisation with asterisks (e.g., “f*ck”)?

Tags: writing, offensive-language

I have always been intrigued by the English use of asterisks to replace vowels in words considered as offensive, and the reasons it seems somewhat language-specific. My (very related) questions on this are:

- Is there a name for this process? This is encompassed by *bowdlerisation*, but is there a more specific way to refer to it?
- This works fairly well for short words (f*ck, sh*t, c*nt), but how is it used with longer words, if deemed offensive (I can't think of any long word that would be very offensive, maybe that makes this a non-question)?

---

In my native French, words are typically bowlderized with first letter and an ellipsis: *“M..., tu es vraiment c...!”* (*Sh*t, you're such a dumb-*ss!*). It's a bit dated, though.

Comment: Bowdleris(/z)ation seems right. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Profanity/Archive_2#Quoting_from_censored_sources

Comment: @JoseK: it does cover it, but it's too wide: if I rewrote some text with “egad” instead of “shit”, it would still be a sort of bowdlerisation

Comment: True - let's wait and see if there's something more precise. :)

Comment: Symbol swearing comes to mind, but that is just a %&/() guess

Comment: I would have said _censure_, but it is in fact wider as _bowdlerisation_, IMO.

Comment: [Off topic:] I once had an apparently orthodox Jewish philosophy teacher who wrote `G*d` on the blackboard in our classes about Plato, Nietze etc. He mentioned that it was something about Jewish religion but failed to elaborate. I imagined it had something to do with (primitive) Near-Eastern notions that portraying certain things, like God, humand beings, etc. was sacrilege. Has anyone ever seen this? My teacher was Dutch, and Dutch normally wouldn't censor with asterisks.

Comment: @Eldros: Perhaps you meant *censor*, not *censure*. To censure someone is to reprimand/rebuke/express disapproval of/condemn that person.

Comment: @Cer: As advs89 [commented](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14537/why-is-god-a-common-noun-capitalized/14540#14540), it's "the name 'God' should never be disposed of. By writing 'G-d', they can safely discard the paper without being disrespectful". Same on [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-d#In_English): "written by many Jews as 'G-d' and 'L-rd' as a way of avoiding writing a name of God, so as to avoid the risk of sinning by erasing or defacing his name.… The general rabbinic opinion is that this only applies to the sacred Hebrew names of God—but not to the word "God" in English"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yeah, I was reffering to _censorship_, which would be reffered as _censure_ in French.

Comment: How about 'bleeping'? Although not really accurate, and not a very... scientific word, but the intention is the same, censor profanity by covering it with something. In an audio stream it's a bleep, in text it's black-out, and in lack of that, an asterisk. Come to think of it, 'black out' is also a possibility.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Ah, thank you! Now I see the logic. Funny that my teacher should have been more orthodox than general rabbinic opinion. The censored word felt a bit... intrusive, as religion is usually anathema in universities here.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning "redact" as a relevant word.  It _does_ have meaning beyond the typical government-censorship connotation.

Comment: Often this is used for more than one letter, like *f**k*, or "*f***ing c****".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bowdlerization is clearly much broader in scope, as it refers to the general editing of any text to remove potentially offensive content.

The substitution of letters in profanities with asterisks or other characters was a practical solution for U.S. and U.K. publishers in the 20th century, devised to avoid the possibility of prosecution for the violation of obscenity laws.

In the U.S., 7 words were considered profane and their use forbidden in radio, television and most sorts of printed media. Those were: shit, fuck, piss, cunt, cocksucker, motherfucker, tits. These words are still not used on the major American television networks or in some publications (national newspapers such as the "New York Times", etc.).

One term invented in 1980 to describe textual symbols meant to represent profanities is "grawlix/grawlixes". Other suggestions for the same thing are "obscenicons" or "maledicta". These refer to e.g. old comic strips in which the dialog bubbles of characters sometime contain expressions like "@#*!%!", meant to represent a profanity.

See http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2457