# What the #$@&%*! is that called?

Tags: writing, offensive-language, symbols

Is there a name for the use of symbols in place of curse words, for example `#$@&%*!`?

Comment: An answer to this [ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15036/24117) also offers *maledicta*.

Comment: That's the best ☠@✴#ing question title I've ever seen.

Comment: Not to be outdone by the special interest groups and their pretentious little dictionaries of coined terms that they would be delighted if the rest of the world adopted (see the various answers below), I hereby propose: *depletives*, a portmanteau of *deleted expletives*.

Comment: Ah, *maledicta*. That brings me way back. When I graduated from high school, I was the maledictorian. :)

Comment: Another proposition: these are not exactly dirty words, but usually the order of the characters depends on a particular keyboard layout, hence we might call them *qwerty words*.

Comment: I think I've seen it referred to as _unnecessary censoring_.

Comment: @Kaz: The order certainly disagrees with my keyboard layout. Also, I tend to arrange them "meaningfully", e.g. $#!+

Comment: @jasperloy, that title drove a ton of viewers to this site - why change it???

Comment: This question is so !$*%ing awesome

Comment: It's Perl code.

Comment: I'd call it a strong password

Comment: Here are some suitable emojis (use Code 2000 to see them) for this purpose:

㡪⚓⚔†⚡꩜ #⃣☠

Please add more suggestions if you can!

Comment: One of few awesome tiles not on Arcade SE.

Comment: related question - is there a "right" way to do this? E.g. is "[SHIFT] 1 2 3 4 5" the defacto standard or is there even one? I tried googling various combinations and got nowhere.

Comment: @user9645 I think it's just random.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I found the term "grawlixes" here: [The Lexicon of Comicana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lexicon_of_Comicana).

> **Grawlixes**
>   Typographical symbols standing for profanities, appearing in dialogue balloons in place of actual dialogue.

I also came across the terms "profanitype" and "symbol swearing." I think I like "grawlixes" best.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SymbolSwearing also uses "graxlixes", and also "profanitype".

Comment: @naught101 Oh for grawlixes' sake, don't link to tvtropes. There goes my evening...

Comment: *Grawlix* won't work. Just Google it and you'll see why. *Profanitype* works but sounds and looks too much like stereotype, even though "-type" is supposed to relate to typewriting. Zairja has the answer(s): *Bleep* is not a **name** for *!@#$%^&** but rather a spoken **equivalent** of it, as is *blankety-blank* (my substantive contribution to this thread). The winner, so far: ***Obscenicon***. (Good going, Zairja!)

Comment: @HStephenStraight Can you elaborate on why Grawlix won't work? I didn't find any google hit that did not confirm this. Although the meaning of Obscenicon is probably easier to guess without prior knowledge...

Answer (score 50):

These have also been called [*obscenicons*](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2457). Several links on Language Log offer an in-depth look at their usage.

[More on the early days of obscenicons](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2483)
[Obscenicons a century ago](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2457)
[CALL ME... UNPRONOUNCEABLE](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002461.html)

The "word" represented by the symbols could be pronounced *bleep*:

> So people came up with a small set of conventional euphemistic readings for `<`expletive suppressed`>`: "bleep", "bleeping", "bleepity-bleep", "blankety-blank", and so on.  Of these, "bleep" seems to have pretty much won out, as (again) Geoff noted in his first posting.  And, indeed, the IMDB lists the movie *What the #$*! Do We Know!?* as *What the Bleep Do We Know!?*  So there now is a conventional way for pronouncing the name of the movie.

You might refer to such symbols as "bleeps" though YMMV.

Answer (score 17):

These can also be called *swear symbols* or *curse symbols*, as evidenced by [this quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/d/daniel_clowes_2.html):

> *But I enjoy the opportunity to use swear symbols*.
>   ([Daniel Clowes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Clowes), Cartoonist)

Those terms are not as cool as the word [*grawlix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grawlix), but they are still in the vernacular, and thus worthy of a mention.

Answer (score 3):

I've always heard and referred to this as "comic cursing" in the US Northeast, but I can't find a citation and also haven't discussed this particular topic very often.

Answer (score 3):

Comics artists sometimes call them *grawlixes* and sometimes "swear symbols". Their use is referred to as "symbol swearing".

The closest way to duplicate their effect in speech is to bleep (electronically if you've the means, or just making a bleep dound), since such bleeps serve the same purpose with audible speech in television or radio, as they do in print.

Answer (score 1):

I've always known it as *symbolic substitution* — but have no idea where I learned the phrase. Interestingly enough, the English language contains more descriptive words than any other language — completely negating the need for symbolic substitution in the first place.

Another word I've seen used for it is *symtax*, but I prefer symbolic substitution because it is self explanatory by definition.

Comment: Citation needed for "the English language contains more descriptive words than any other language". What is a "descriptive word" anyway?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, it is a member of that class of words of which the English language contains more than any other language.

Answer (score 0):

*Redactions*? It would be more typical to use a verb — such as saying that the swear words *had been censored* or *redacted*.

Comment: That would usually imply something more like blacking out, or crossing off.