# Does the word 'God' with a capital G have a plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

Does the word 'God' with a capital G have a plural form?

Comment: Why do you ask?  Is this for a a particular religion, or a science fiction novel, etc.?  It seems like a cultural and religious matter without any more context....

Comment: Sure: it's "Gods".

Comment: Related: [When should the word “God” be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/)

Answer (score 11):

This is not a problem of monotheistic preference.

When capitalised, the word god is a proper name.  So from the pure grammatical point of view, it can have a plural form in the same way as John or Peter (credits to jgelacqua's comments)

It's like Yahweh or Elohim (actually this is a plural I believe - which shows that monotheism in the bible is a fuzzy notion).

Comment: Yet we could say, 'OK, all of the Bobs and Charlies form a line over here, Daves and Erics form a line down there.'

Comment: As @jgbelacqua points out from a grammatical point of view you could use proper names in the plural, but I struggle to think of a case in any world view where this would ever occur unless some freaks used it as a child name and they all got together.

Comment: As for Elohim being plural it isn't that the idea of monotheism is a fuzzy notion. The God of the bible is ONE, but has three distinct persons that make up that entity, all being fully God in nature and essence. It is even found that God refers to himself in first person plural, "let us" or "our". This is almost always combined with a first person singular in the same sentence emphasizing that there is still only one identity at stake even if He has multiple persons.

Comment: @Caleb, Sorry but the dogma of the Holy Trinity is much more recent than the word Elohim.  If you wish to know why Elohim is a plural in the bible, please have a look at the exegete's works regarding this topic.

Comment: @Caleb that's but one take on it. The doctrine of the Trinity is not in the Bible.

Comment: @jgbelacqua, Correct ! Assuming somebody wants to create (sorry has been revealed) his own religion with 2 gods, both of them named God, then, from the purely grammatical point of view, he would be entitled to write "Gods".  Assuming he would use English as one of  the languages in which to write his sacred/revealed texts, as so many other religions also do.  Conversely, considering that so many English speakers have non monotheistic religions, the plural form might have some favour.

Comment: There are no capital letters in Hebrew.

Comment: +1 for plural form. This is pretty much how it is. When translating old testament text there are many Hebrew names for God that are simply translated God (or Lord, LORD, etc.. depending on name/context) The Hebrew concept of God is a monotheistic god but with many sides/faces/personalities. The compassionate God, the wrathful God, God as judge, God as forgiver, and so on. At some points they refer to multiple personalities collectively in a plural form. I don't know of an english translation that conveys this. Usually in the new testament greek God is simply 'Theos'.

Comment: @Caleb, I've used it in explaining the name confusions we had in a team once, where we had two Peters, two Jons, and two Annas.

Comment: @Garet. Good comment.  Please consider another example in the Greek Pantheon. Adonais comes as an implicit plural form.  And guess what ? It's from oriental origin as well !

Comment: @Alain ack how did I not consider Adonais! I had not heard about this though. Any resource on the oriental etymology?

Comment: @Garet, I read that eons ago in a French book but you can find some hints (and a relation to non other than Yahweh himself) in [this paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adonis#Origin_of_the_cult) of the wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 6):

"God" is a proper noun. While proper nouns can be pluralized in some cases, it is not very common, and especially not so with "God".

However, I *can* think of an example. Here is an example with the proper noun, "Bob":

> How many Bobs would it take to beat up Charlie?

That is, if Bob could be copied and the copies could fight Charlie, how many would it take to beat up Charlie?
This example can be revisited with the proper noun, "God":

> How many Gods would it take to beat up Satan?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, why not?

If I don't presuppose that the term refers to one Supreme Being, I can imagine that there are more Supreme Beings.  Gods and Goddesses.  Unsurprisingly, the word "Gods" does appear in writing.  What about the Fates, the Graces, the Norns?   Burger Kings or Targets or KwikMarts?   What about Egyptians or Armenians, Tudors and Plantagenets, or Kochs or Kardashians?

An interesting construction I discovered on a [Hindu information site](http://www.hindunet.org/god/summary/index.htm) is "Forms of God" (as well as "Forms of Goddess").   This is an interesting plural, for a presumably (but not necessarily) different God-concept.

I suppose it a philosophical, religious, and/or metaphysical question whether the capitalized "God" is a name, a description, an honorary label, or something else.  The different possibilities don't change the fact that mechanically, you can pluralize God.  Whether one does so or not will depend on the meaning of the of the name/symbol/label to that person or group.

Comment: No, there can't be more than one Supreme Being, any more than there can be more than one largest member of a set. (There may be none, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. My intuition suggests that the convention is the capital 'G' is singular and reserved for monotheistic, Abrahamic religions and the lower-case usage is used in conjunction with other faiths which, it is of course assumed are polytheistic and therefore `wrong`.

I think of the sentence 'worshiping false **gods** so it sort of depends on the context. You'd never write '... our Gods' unless of course you were writing the speech for a `heathen` character.

Comment: I believe the actual usage is that the capital is used for a deity the speaker believes in.  In which case "Gods" cannot be used by a monotheist, by easily by a polytheist.

Answer (score 3):

It might be illustrative to compare it to something more unique than a person's proper name. While we expect there to be many Bobs and Johns, talking about "Gods" may be more like talking about "Englands" or "Swedens". Or "Princes" or "Madonnas"…

Grammatically sound, semantically a little strange, but possible. I suppose you could say things like "Traffic-wise, there aren't many Englands in this world" and "Stricture-wise, there aren't many Gods in religion".

Then again, people use "God" to refer to quite different concepts. I'm sure you could argue that two different persons' Gods (!) are as different as two different Bobs.

Comment: A more natural example of plural country names is "Koreas".

Comment: @user744 Good point. I suppose also Congos and possibly Chinas (what with Taiwan).

Answer (score 0):

No. There are no known religions whose translation(s) of their scripturs or theology into English or tradition in English allow a plural and capitalized name 'Gods'.

Comment: Disagree. Let's imagine we are writing a story about a religious play in which we have Jesus, God, Mary, et al. And there is an understudy for God. So there's two of them. In one line of dialogue, the director might say, "OK, I want Jesus over there, and I need both Gods to come over here." It's possible.

Comment: The Greek or Hindu pantheon of Gods ...?

Comment: @5arx: That might be appropriate, except that in English, spoken (as a first language) in a  predominantly Christian culture, you would properly refer to a set of members of those entities as 'gods'. Why is 'I', the first person singular pronoun, always capitalized, but 'you' is not? Kinda egotistical, but that's what they do.

Comment: @Mitch - Its a language that supports the Abrahamic monotheistic cultures so I guess its appropropriate. I would *always* use a capital G for 'God/s' regardless myself. Anything else would be disrespectful to the Almighty(ies) ;-)

Comment: @5arx, Most polytheists are happy to refer to their gods with lowercase.

Comment: @TRiG - you have no evidence whatsover to back up this claim. I for one always capitalise.

Comment: @5arx, The polytheists I hang around with at The Slacktiverse use a lowercase *g*, and so did those at H2G2. (I've not seen polytheists at H2G2 in a while.)

Comment: That's hardly 'evidence'. I would suggest taking a look at some 'polytheist' literature might be a more academic approach.

Comment: @5arx: don't you see a problem with the word "Almighties"?

Comment: Not really - you appear to have handled the pluralisation correctly ;-)

Comment: @5arx, Is there any literature you'd recommend?

I saw plural *Gods* for the first time today in page two of the comments at http://slacktivist.typepad.com/slacktivist/2011/06/at-patheos-tf-how-not-to-do-evangelism.html.

Comment: I wouldn't 'recommend' or indeed categorise them as 'literature', but for the purposes of backing-up my argument re: usage, I would, off the top of my head point you towards Erich von Daniken's work:  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_von_D%C3%A4niken#Bibliography) an obvious example - lots of titles taking the form 'X of the Gods'

Comment: @5arx: so close! I'm not convinced by that because the capitalization comes from that for beng in a title.

Comment: @Mitch - Jeez, what do you want, b l o o d ?  ;-)