# When should we write the word "church" with a capital C?

Tags: orthography

When should we write the word "church" with a capital C, *Church*, and when should we only write it as *church*?

Comment: Part of the answer is given here (if it is part of a proper noun like "the Church of England", it should be capitalized): [Should words be capitalized for being religious terms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97020)

Comment: The Church as a body is capitalised as shown in [this British Library article](https://www.bl.uk/the-middle-ages/articles/church-in-the-middle-ages-from-dedication-to-dissent). I'd extend this to local bodies as well as the Church Universal. This is the same usage as say 'Parliament' for the body. However, the non-specific building (turn left at the church with the crooked spire) and less specific non-concrete usages (He attends church) use the common noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to leave this as an answer, but my rep isn't high enough yet to comment.

Piggybacking off of @sumelic's comment in the original post, I would say any time you want to highlight the organization of a certain church (and the full weight that its name carries), I would capitalize it.

For example, [in this article here](http://www.christiantoday.com/article/church.of.england.to.debate.suggestions.on.sexuality/103146.htm).

To give my own example sentence, I would say, "The Catholic Church has been known to blah blah blah, but the Church as it stands nowadays blah blah blah."

Does this help?

Comment: yes thank you it did! but i think the second one" but the Church as it stands nowadays blah blah blah", should be in small c?

Comment: @Nona No, because it's still referring to the organization of the Catholic Church as a whole, such as in [the article I had cited in my answer](http://www.christiantoday.com/article/church.of.england.to.debate.suggestions.on.sexuality/103146.htm). Think of "Church" as the last name of the "Catholic Church" and you'll understand better what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of ***[proper nouns vs common nouns](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_proper_and_common_nouns.htm):***

> - According to Lord Davies, ***The Church in London*** is not actually ***a church*** but a public house.
>
> (The Church is a proper noun. The word church is a common noun.)

(Grammar-Monster)

Comment: do you say the local church? and one Church? for instance?