# When should the word "Nature" be capitalized?

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

This question is similar to the question "[When should the word "God" be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/when-should-the-word-god-be-capitalized)" but somewhat trickier, because the distinction here is, I think, more subtle than the distinction between using "God" as a proper name to refer to one particular monotheistic divine being and using "god" as a reference to one divine being among many.

Sometimes when people talk about natural philosophy or physics they use the word nature in the sense that "This equation is a law of Nature.", or "This is how Nature is.", or "As scientists, we hope to understand Nature."

But, capitalization of the word Nature when used in this sense does not seem to be entirely consistent and may have political or religious connotations.

Under what circumstances should the word "Nature" be capitalized (other, of course, than at the beginning of a sentence or as the proper name of a publication)?

Comment: My bad. I didn't catch that in a search, and may have simply not gone down the list far enough. Thanks. Although the answer isn't as rich as one might like.