# What is 'there is a God' supposed to mean?

Tags: indefinite-articles, proper-nouns, existential-constructions

There's no denying that the phrase **there is a God** is in use, as shown in these examples.

[*The New York Times*, 2020](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/28/books/review/barry-gewen-inevitability-of-tragedy-henry-kissinger.html):

> When the nefarious Cardinal Richelieu died in 1642, Pope Urban VIII is said to have declared: “If **there is a God**, the Cardinal de Richelieu will have much to answer for. If not … well, he had a successful life.”
>
> ...
>
> Pope Urban had it right. If **there is a God**, Kissinger has much to answer for.

[*The New York Times*, 2019](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/03/books/review/one-long-river-of-song-brian-doyle.html):

> If **there is a God** — and Doyle fervently believed there is — “One Long River of Song” will change all that.

Granted, the phrase should be grammatical given that we have many of these attested example written by educated writers, but I've got some questions about the use of the indefinite article **a** along with the capitalized **God**.

The first question is whether **God** here is a proper noun or a common noun, which is nicely answered by @nohat in [a 2010 ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3141/118290):

> To summarize the proper noun/common noun usage, I think the easiest way to handle the situation is to capitalize the word *god* when it is used as a proper name as the name of the god of a monotheistic religion, such as the god of Christianity or Judaism, and not capitalize it when it is used as a common noun:

So it looks like **God** here "is used as a proper name as the name of the god of a monotheistic religion, such as the god of Christianity or Judaism".

Then comes the second question: If it's a proper noun, how could you possibly add the indefinite article?

Grammatical names aside, does **a God** still refer to "the god of a monotheistic religion, such as the god of Christianity or Judaism"?

Moreover, the following article even has the expression **that God**:

[*The New York Times*, 2017](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/06/opinion/if-we-are-not-just-animals-what-are-we.html#:%7E:text=If%2C%20as%20many%20people%20believe,nature%2C%20just%20as%20He%20is.):

> If, as many people believe, **there is a God**, and **that God** made us in his own image, then of course we are distinct from nature, just as He is.

So, now you can add the demonstrative determiner **that** as well as the indefinite article before a proper noun. What's going on here?

Considering all this, I'm not sure I even understand what the phrase **there is a God** is supposed to mean. Please help.

---

Here's a new example worth considering:
[*The New York Times*, 2022](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/08/14/opinion/god-culture-war-politics.html):

> Is there **a God**? If there is, can we interact with him, her or it? If so, how? Can **God** speak to us? Can **God** say no to us?

Here, the writer initially wrote **a God**, but then changed it to just **God** without any article. Apparently, the writer is referring to the same entity. What does this tell us?

Comment: I think you are mixing religious concepts with ordinary speech. If you want to understand the above sentences forget about the former and concentrate on the latter.

Comment: Why can't one use an indefinite article with a name? "Is anyone in this town named Horatio?" "Yes, we have a Horatio, and he lives over there."

Comment: @nohat's answer to which you refer is simplistic, and part of your problem. It's not a proper noun here; it's a common noun with a capital letter because there is only one God. All the other gods are false. It's related to (but not the same as) capitalising pronouns like His, Thy, Your etc when referring to that deity. And this is a comment because I don't really know how to answer a question which is based on a false premise.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Although I have cited nohat's answer as "an" answer to my first question and then presented my second question, you certainly can post an answer that rejects nohat's answer and start from there. So I don't understand why you don't know how to answer it.

Comment: @Gio I'm purely looking at it as a grammar question. Where in my question do you suggest I'm "mixing religious concepts with ordinary speech"?

Comment: Closing this seems a little harsh. There is a legitimate question: what is the difference between "a God" and "a god"? I don't know if the slightly aggressive tone or the mere mention of God has upset people.

Comment: "Is there a Golden Gate Bridge?"  I believe there is, even though I have never seen it in person.

Comment: I do understand your point, and I believe that it is valid. However there are cases where proper nouns _can_ be preceded by articles. The comment by @GEdgar is one and the question "Is there a James in your family" is another.

Comment: @BoldBen I'm well aware of those cases where proper nouns can be preceded by articles. It's just that this particular case is clearly different from those cases. I believe article usage is all about the speaker's perspective. When the speaker says _a God_, they would assume a monotheistic religion, e.g., Christianity or Islam. Here, they can't normally be assuming both Christianity and Islam, unlike the normal cases where proper nouns are preceded by articles, as in: _Is there a John here?_, where the speaker should assume that there can be more than one John in the world they live in.

Comment: If this is about writing, why is _God_ capitalized? That assumes it's a proper name, and that assumes it's the name of a unique person. So it already assumes monotheism, and since it's English, make that Christian monotheism. If, on the other hand, you pointed to a statue of Ganesha, you could say _There is a god_, but you wouldn't hafta capitalize it; you could just point at a statue of Hanuman and say _And there's another god._

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not just asking why it's capitalized. I'm asking why the proper noun _God_ has an indefinite article, when the context doesn't allow the existence of any other 'God' in the world the speaker lives in, unlike such cases as "Is there a John?".

Comment: @listeneva These kind folks are just trying to tell you this usage is an error. We'd be potentially off mark in attempting to explain why the mistake was made, and we probably can't generalize. But this usage is not grammatical. It's just errata. There is no why.

Comment: Probably each author, upon the act of writing, was so heavily influenced by Christian, Catholic, or Jewish convention (where God is used as a name for their god) that they simply employed a habitual tendency to always capitalize the word "god". But as to why? Who can guess? Ignorance, optics (especially for publications meant for a specific community), or fear (of defying the convention) are all standout possibilities. And there are probably far more.

Comment: IMO it's a fudge between a statement considering whether polytheism is correct or whether monotheism is correct. 'If there is a Loch Ness Monster' is used as well as the lower-cased-m variant, and reflects the respectful/recognitional handling of even a postulated but pretty well-specified (most have seen artists' impressions, pictures of plesiosaurs etc, at least) creature.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that anybody can give a definite answer to this question. If one were to ask the people who write 'a God', what exactly they had in mind when they combined the indefinite article with what appears to be a proper name, chances are that they wouldn't have an answer readily available. Two hypotheses about what is going on here can, however, be offered.

**(1)** *God* is here simply a common noun, and the people who write 'if there is a God' capitalise it in error. The cause of the error is that the adherents of a particular monotheistic religion develop the habit of capitalising the word in the context of that religion, and then unthinkingly act on that habit even when they are outside that context.

**(2)** *God* here has a meaning that is between its broad common-noun sense (any god of any religion) and being a proper noun (God, as postulated by a specific monotheistic religion). Those who write 'if there is a God' probably want to set aside polytheistic religions, and focus on the monotheistic ones, but, at the same time do not want to limit what they are saying to one specific religion. On this hypothesis, 'if there is a God' is a shorthand for something like 'if there is a god whose characteristics roughly accord with what the major monotheistic religions have in common (but that may or may not accord with the details of any one of them)'. The wording combines multiplicity and uniqueness: it covers the multiplicity of different conceptions of a being that is, within each of these conceptions, unique.

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to something I have been hypothesizing myself when thinking about the question, but is only better thought out. Did you just come up with this answer after reading my question? Or is this something you've thought about before? Also, would there be any resources to cite to support your answer?

Comment: I've added a new example.

Comment: (2) Sound analysis. Agreed. Those (monotheists) who believe accord their god a proper name "God". "If there is a God" asks the reader to consider the existence of such a single god.

Answer (score 4):

I understand ***If there is a God*** as, ***If there is any (divine) justice in this world***. Whereas ***There is a God!***, as shown in the comments, expresses the positive acknowledgement that ***miracles do happen***.

Technically, the presence of the indefinite article has very much to do with 'the existential construction' ***there is*** which requires the presence of a determiner when used with countable nouns. [YourDict](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/there-is-there-are) explains:

> - *There is **a** **student*** in class today. (countable)
> - *There is **smoke*** in the air. (uncountable)
>
> Notice the determiner, such as ***a*** or ***one***, when the noun is countable (student). You can replace these determiners or add adjectives — for example,
>
> - There is *another new student* in class today.
>
> When the noun is uncountable (smoke), you don’t need a determiner after ***is***, but you can add one anyway
>
> - *There is so much smoke* in the air.

If you think of proper nouns, you would never say:

> *There is John in every community.

but

> There is ***a*** John in every community.

This site about academic writing from the *[Lund University](https://www.awelu.lu.se/language/selective-mini-grammar/pronouns/dummy-pronouns/)* explains:

> The postponed subject [following *there is*] has ***indefinite reference***. Thus *definite noun phrases, e.g. proper nouns, pronouns with definite reference, e.g. personal pronouns, or full noun phrases introduced by definite determiners* ***are only possible with the so called ‘list’ reading***:
>
> - Well, there’s Bill… and John, and maybe a few others.

Comment: In the first and third examples of the OP, "If there is a God" doesn't really mean "If there is any (divine) justice in this world", does it? // So you think that the OP's "God" is a proper noun, and that it is accompanied by "a" simply because it's used in the existential construction. But "There is a John" means not that there's only one person named "John", but that there's at least one such person. However, "There is a God" doesn't mean in the OP's examples that there's at least one entity named "God", does it?

Comment: I've added a new example.

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite article in this case means "some form of."

> If there is *some form of* God ...

There's an actor called Brad Pitt. Or is there? Maybe, just maybe, there's a bunch of look-alikes acting in movies, donating to charities, marrying and divorcing, but they're mere doubles? Wouldn't that be something!

> So, if there is *a* Brad Pitt, he must be a very private person.

Or:

> So, if there is *some form of* Brad Pitt, he must be a very private
> person.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've added a new example.

Comment: @listeneva: Yes. Is there a Listeneva? Does some form of Listeneva exist? If he or she or it does, can we speak to him, her, or it? Would this Listeneva answer us? Can Listeneva say no to us?

Comment: I don't believe that the phrase "If there is a God" in the OP means "If there is some form of God". They all mean "If God exists", not "If some form of God exists".

Comment: @listeneva: But it does. "If there is a(n) Alaska, Australia, Vatican, Milky Way, Johnnie Cash, Giacomo Puccini, listeneva, gas known as oxygen, Sun, King of Belgium ..." and on and on.

Comment: When someone says "If there is a God", they're asking about the very existence of God, not the existence of "some form of God", whatever that means. Are you saying that "If God exists" means "If some form of God exists"?

Comment: In other words, if you don't believe that there is a God, you're either an atheist or an agnostic. No?

Comment: @listeneva: 1. Agnostics are expected to have no opinion one way or the other. 2. In Christian culture and Christian tradition "God" means "the Creator of everything that exists AND the Lord, in one." So, yes, when someone asks "Does God exist?" it is implied that they mean the biblical God and no other. Just like you did earlier. 3. Technically and linguistically, "Is there a God?" means "some form." The God of the Gnostics, for instance, is a notion that differs sharply from the Christian version.

Comment: If the choice between _a God_ and _God_ (zero article) is simply a semantic one, as you suggest, I can't think of any reason why we don't normally say _Does a God exist?_ instead of _Does God exist?_, can you?

Comment: @listeneva: It doesn't FEEL right. What can I tell you. Every language has its quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks why an indefinite article would be used with something that is considered to be unique. That is, if there is only one, how can references to it be anything other than definite?

Grammatically, there are (at least) two situations where this would arise.

1. When you are allowing multiple instances for sake of argument, such as in the protasis of a conditional:

- If I'm speaking with anyone, I'm speaking with you

Even in the case that I am speaking only with you, the protasis considers the possibility that I might be speaking with someone else - even though in reality, there is no one else I am speaking with.

2. Pointing out that there is (at least) one instance.

- There is a bowl of fruit on the table.

Even if the table only has one bowl of fruit and there is no possibility of a second, you can use the indefinite article as a synonym for "one" - "there is one bowl of fruit on the table". Using the indefinite article instead of a number removes the stress on the number.

Your quote combines both of these ideas, particularly the second:

- If ... there is a God, and that God made us in his own image, then ... .

Whether "God" is a common noun or proper noun depends on the author's intent. Even if it was intended as a proper noun, the grammar does not need to constrain "if there is a God" to exactly one individual. Here, though, the choice is not between one and many, but between none and one. The term "that God" is simply referring back to the antecedent "a God". This is common usage - e.g.

- There is an apple on the table. The/that apple is red.

The first reference to "apple" uses an indefinite article, but the second reference refers to the first as its specified instance, so a definite article (or an equivalent) is appropriate.

Comment: New York Times journalist Erin Marquis once tweeted, "I hope there is a God and they met that God someday." So, I'm afraid your first point is moot. As for your second point, the very reason that _bowl_ is a common noun is that it doesn't refer to a specific bowl, and that 'bowl' doesn't carry any uniqueness. Even when you use a proper noun as in _Is there a John here?_, _John_ doesn't carry any uniqueness. But how about _God_ in Erin Marquis's tweet? I don't know about you, but I'm pretty sure she's specifically talking about the Christian god.

Comment: @listeneva That's the point of the 'embedded-in-conditional' idea. Even though she had the Christian God in mind, the conditional abstracts out some specifics. Making the noun less specific allows her to use the indefinite article.

Comment: What 'conditional' are you talking about? There's no conditional in her utterance. Also, what is the 'embedded-in-conditional' idea? Honestly, I don't understand a single sentence from your last comment. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @listeneva A sentence of the form "If <condition> (then) <assertion>" is called a conditional. Someone saying "If you chose black you win" isn't saying that you chose black - they're saying that winning is conditional on (i.e. depends on) you having chosen black. If you didn't actually choose black then you didn't win, but it doesn't make their statement wrong. By "embedded-in-conditional", I meant that the phrase "there is a god" is in the "if <condition>" part. At this point, the speaker isn't yet narrowing the term "god" to the Christian God, so she could say "a god" rather than "the God".

Comment: But in Erin Marquis's tweet, there's no "if".

Comment: @listeneva My answer was referring to the NYT quote in your question: "If, as many people believe, ...", and my comments built on that. It was my mistake to think that your initial comment about _NYT_ journalist Erin Marquis was referring to the same. The Erin Marquis tweet in your initial comment is something of a non-sequitur to my answer. In that quote, "a God" leaves open the possibility of 'at least one', but "that God" then clarifies that in her context, there is only 'at most one'. That is, she allows the possibility of no God, but if there is one, then there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any uncapitalized god would do. Only one conceived as the ultimate source of cosmic justice. As in, "Is there a god as omnipotent and just as the one the Christians call God"?

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite article **a** in this particular context indicates that the subject of the question, God, is being considered *hypothetically*, not as one of many, or an instance of a class.

**Let's suppose, for the sake of argument, that there exists **a** Supreme Being people have named "God".**

There can be only one Supreme Being, as the adjective indicates. But the existence of **a** Supreme Being is not a given, at least not in the minds of those who are considering the Supreme Being only on a hypothetical basis.

Consider:

> They claim to have seen a pig flying in the sky above their small village. The pig, they say, has golden wings, and they have named it "The Golden Sow". Now supposing there is **a Golden Sow**, would it fall under the laws of this commonwealth governing farm animals? Or would the Federal Aviation Administration be the appropriate body to consult?

To paraphrase, "supposing there is **such a being which people refer to as "The Golden Sow"**.

**The** Golden Sow implies existence and uniqueness, whereas **a** Golden Sow concedes those attributes only on a hypothetical basis. The indefinite article is this kind of context might be accompanied by the speaker putting the noun in "scare quotes".

Answer (score -1):

The Cambridge English Dictionary, on punctuation and grammar says the following:-

> Punctuation: capital letters (B, D) and full stops (.)
> We use capital letters to mark the beginning of a sentence and we use full stops to mark the end of a sentence:

> We went to France last summer. We were really surprised that it was so easy to travel on the motorways.

> The Football World Cup takes place every four years. The next World Cup will be held in South Africa. In 2006 it was held in Germany.

> We also use capital letters at the beginning of proper nouns. Proper nouns include personal names (including titles before names), nationalities and languages, days of the week and months of the year, public holidays as well as geographical places:

> Dr David James is the consultant at Leeds City Hospital.

> They are planning a long holiday in New Zealand.

> Can she speak Japanese?

> The next meeting of the group will take place on Thursday.

> What plans do you have for Chinese New Year?

> We use capital letters for the titles of books, magazines and newspapers, plays and music:

> ‘Oliver’ is a musical based on the novel ‘Oliver Twist’ by Charles Dickens.

> The Straits Times is a daily English language newspaper in Singapore.

> They are performing Beethoven’s Sixth Symphony.

> In addition to closing sentences, we also use full stops in initials for personal names:

> G. W. Dwyer

> David A. Johnston, Accountant

> Full stops are also used after abbreviations, although this practice is becoming less common.

It omits one semi-usage, which is the use of (or reference to) capitals as a mark of the importance (or scale) of the item or being referred to.  I mean **importance with a capital I**.

As has been already said, if you are a polytheist, each of the recognised deities has a proper name, so capitals are not required.  Moreover, there is no reason to feel the need to use a capital in the sentence "I believe there exists at least one god."

If, however, you have like I have, grown up with a monotheistic religion, you will know that the word God is actually being used as the name of this single and only deity in prayer.  And in the Hebrew world the proper (small 'p') name of the one deity cannot even be uttered.

There is a further use of the capital (or the idea of the capital) when we refer to degrees of importance and speak of being, for example, conservative with a 'capital' or 'small' *c* (or should I have written *C*?).  The same deity often has a capital H at the beginning of the personal pronoun when it refers to Him.  So for Christians, or even lapsed Christians, like me, the name of the single deity has become a proper name.

So the problem is a real one, but is a state more of mind than of punctuation.