# What's the difference between "I believe in God" and "I believe in a God"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning, articles, indefinite-articles

I've recently heard these two examples where I don't understand what "a" is supposed to emphasize:

1. Somebody asks: "Do you believe in God?" Then gets this reply: "I believe in **a** God".
2. One says "the primary conflict, or rather **a** primary conflict".

What this emphasized "a" supposed to mean?

Comment: @BrianDonovan Then "I believe in the God" would mean "there is only one God and I believe in him"?

Comment: There's a related question on [there is (a) God](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594678/what-is-there-is-a-god-supposed-to-mean).

Comment: The point of the answer in #1 is that they're suggesting that the god they believe in is not necessarily the same as the one that the asker intends. E.g. the question is presumably about the Christian god, but the answerer is Muslim.

Comment: The difference is that the latter has a capitalization error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indefinite article 'a' here **emphasizes indefiniteness in the response**.

In the first question, a word is left implicit: "Do you believe in [this] God?" (In the North American/European tradition, at least, 'this God' is almost certainly the Christian one.) The reply "I believe in **a** God" affirms some brand of theism, but leaves intentionally ambiguous *which* God is meant, or perhaps signifies that the replier means a *different* God. Or more than one, as a commenter suggested.

In the second case, I expect that the (specific) "primary conflict" about to be discussed is—at first glance—**the** primary conflict, the conflict to which all others are secondary. But clarifying to **a** primary conflict leaves open the possibility that other sources of conflict might compete, even with equal importance. To me, the sentence sentence feels natural as an invitation to think critically about other possible sources of conflict. It might be given for instance by a lecturer.